# Gutenberg's Popover component position relative to the focused element

Tags: plugin-development, block-editor

I am developing a site where we want to use Gutenberg's [Popover component](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/components/popover/) to show custom options in the Popover when a specific key is entered in the block editor. I have used KeyboardShortcuts component to register a new shortcut, now I am trying to integrate the Popover. For some reason, Popover is not getting positioned relative to the focused element in the block editor and it shows in the left corner of the document.

How could we position it in the block editor just like Blocks popover?

Core Block Popover position: https://i.rankmath.com/2FdwJW

Custom Popover position: https://i.rankmath.com/90mvwv

Here is my code:

```
const [ popoverAnchor, setPopoverAnchor ] = useState()
const [ isAllSelected, setIsAllSelected ] = useState( false )
const selectAll = ( e ) => {
    document.activeElement.setAttribute( 'ref', setPopoverAnchor )
    setTimeout( () => {
        setIsAllSelected( true )
    }, 1000 )
}

return (
    <div>
        <KeyboardShortcuts
            shortcuts={ {
                'mod+/': selectAll,
            } }
            bindGlobal="true"
        />
        [cmd/ctrl + A] Combination pressed? { isAllSelected ? 'Yes' : 'No' }
        { isAllSelected && <Popover anchor={ popoverAnchor } yAxis="top" xAxis="right">Popover is toggled!</Popover> }
    </div>
)
```